# Silverlight Event After Creation

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm building some architecture around a Silverlight user control.  The issue I'm having is that I can't find an event to tap into that occurs right after the creation of the user control, like an Activated event.  Is there some event that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the `Loaded` event?

Comment: Yes thanks, I was foolishly shadowing it, didn't realize it was Loaded, and not something Like Load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loaded event should fire when you need it

Comment: Excellent suggestion - shame you made it a few minutes after i mentioned it in the comments.